# Different results ByteArrayOutputStream Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, compression, gzip, bytearrayoutputstream

**UPD:**
For answers about encoding:
Am use UTF-8 everywhere

I'am try use ByteArrayOutputStream on C#.

I have a string of data:

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567896ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567896

For java i use the method:

```
String a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567896ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567896";
byte[] bArr = a.getBytes();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bArr.length);
DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
deflaterOutputStream.write(bArr);
deflaterOutputStream.close();
bArr = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
System.out.println("out: "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bArr));
```

So, for as a result i get the string:

> eJxzdHJ2cXVz9/D08vbx9fMPCAwKDgkNC4+IjEpMSk5JTUvPyMzKzsnNyy8oLCouKS0rr6isMjA0MjYxNTO3sDRzpEw7AHuTKoM=

For C# am use next code:

```
string source = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567896ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567896";
byte[] bArr_source = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
MemoryStream byteArrayOutputStream = new MemoryStream(bArr_source.Length);
DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
dos.Write(bArr_source, 0, bArr_source.Length);
dos.Finish();
dos.Close();
bArr_source = byteArrayOutputStream.ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(bArr_source));
```

But in C# iam get a **different** line:

> eJyly8MBgAAAAMCVMp7Zdr9su+kbovsfRTMsxwuiJCuqphumZTuu5wdhFCdplhdlVTdt1w/jNC/rth/ndT8vAEIwgmI4QWI/+wd7kyqD

**Why is this happening and how can I fix the problem?**

Comment: I would assume that `Base64#getEncoder` (in Java) is using a different character encoding (and thus base 64 encoding) than the one returned from `Convert#ToBase64String` (in C#). You may also have a difference in how they pad the characters (if at all).

Comment: Ignoring for a moment the question of which `DeflaterOutputStream` implementation you are using (since there is no such class in the stock .NET/.NET Core frameworks), at a minimum you have failed to ensure that the character encodings you use are correct. Java defaults to the platform's current encoding, while you're using UTF-8 in the .NET code. If you explicitly pass `"UTF8"` to the Java `getBytes()` method, you should get the same encoding in each. Alternatively, figure out what encoding Java is using, and explicitly use that one in the .NET code.

Comment: am use utf-8 everywhere

Comment: I don't think this is an encoding issue, because the string consists only of ASCII characters; and any encoding that's not the same as ASCII on this range (for example UTF-16) is going to give an output of a different length.

Comment: What exactly is problematic? Surely the important thing is you get the original string back in each case? I would guess there is a difference in deflation occuring

Answer (score 1):

There *is no problem*.

Both results are valid zlib streams with a check value that checks out, and both decompress to the exact same thing.

There is no assurance that two different compressors will produce the same output with the same input. The only assurance is that when you *decompress*, you get the same thing you started with. And you are.

I do find it a little odd that the C# code is producing a dynamic block when the result can be four bytes shorter with a fixed block. I suspect that you are using a much older version of .NET that used a compressor that was poorly written (internally at Microsoft). It now uses zlib, and wouldn't make that mistake. Yet I emphasize, the result is still entirely valid and usable.